# Programmatic focus of web components

Tags: html, accessibility, web-component

What's the proper way to handle programmatic focus of web components?

Calling `focus()` on a web component should focus the appropriate element in the shadow DOM. This means overwriting the focus method.
This is not enough though, because the web browser is not aware that the component is interactive. One consequence it that clicking an anchor pointing to the element will not focus it as it would a native interactive html element like `<button>`. There may be other implications that I'm not aware of.

The only way I know to make an element interactive is to give it a tabindex value. But `tabindex="0"` will create an extra tab stop, while `tabindex="-1"` will remove all tab stops inside the component. So neither works. My next step is to set `tabindex="0"`, then switch the value on `focus()` and `blur()`. It seems crazy to me that I have to do all this hacky work for such a basic requirement (making a web component properly interactive and accessible). Am I missing something? Is there a better solution?

Comment: `tabindex="-1"` is used to allow something to be programatically focusable but not add it to the focus order so it would work fine for this use case. So `tabindex="0"` is "Add this to the focus order of the page in DOM order" and `tabindex="-1"` is "make this item not appear in the focus order of the page, but expose it to JavaScript so I can focus it manually". Are you adding the `tabindex` in the wrong place maybe if this isn't working for you?

Comment: There is long and active discussion on _"selections in shadowDOM"_ : https://github.com/WICG/webcomponents/issues/79

Comment: @GrahamRitchie I'm aware of that, but a side effect of "-1" is that it affects the children. So if I set no tabindex value on <Host> I get 1 tab stop which is what I want as far as keyboard accessibility, but the component itself isn't recognized by the browser as an interactive element. If I set a tabindex value on the Host to make the component officially interactive I either get 2 tab stops (with tabindex="0") or none (tabindex="-1")

Comment: @Danny'365CSI'Engelman did you get the wrong link? This one's about text selection

Comment: I didn't follow that WICG topic to the letter; thought it had everything to with selection and focus in shadowDOM. That WICG issue list is the best place to ask for features. Lead developers from all 4 WHATWG members are active there

Comment: Well the word "focus" doesn't appear in there :) (focusNode is mentioned once, unrelated to my original question). Thank you anyway for pointing me in that direction, a few other issues were definitely of interest!

Comment: https://github.com/WICG/webcomponents/issues/774
https://github.com/WICG/webcomponents/issues/891
https://github.com/WICG/webcomponents/issues/773
https://github.com/WICG/webcomponents/issues/762

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I *was* missing something indeed. Web components have a specific API for this: `delegatesFocus`. [MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ShadowRoot/delegatesFocus).
When set to `true`:

- calling `focus()` on the host element brings the first focusable element within the shadow DOM into focus.
- so does clicking inside the component on any non focusable element
- the tab sequence is unchanged
- `:focus` styles on the host are applied

It's part of the web components specs so no worries about support.